# Need advice with C++ pointers and character-arrays (C-strings)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, character-arrays

first post and I need help with the following question.

"We have a function with three parameters: a pointer to a character array (also known as a C-String), and two pointers to specific characters (we will assume that they point to characters in the C-String).

```
void stringPointerOperation(char* str, char* firstPtr, char* secondPtr){
    cout << str << endl;
    cout << "First character=" << *firstPtr << endl;
    cout << "Second character =" << *secondPtr << endl;
}
```

A. How do we print out the characters from firstPtr to the end of str?

B. How do we find out how many characters are between firstPtr and secondPtr? "

Now I'm thinking that i need to use a for loop on the array and print out each value, though I am not sure how to do this with a C-string. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're right about using any-kind-of-a-loop.  What's your best attempt?

Comment: cout << firstptr << endl;  cout << higherPtr - lowerPtr << endl;

Answer (score 2):

If I read your question correctly, if you have the string `"Hello world!"`, then if `firstPtr` points to the second `'l'` in `"Hello"` and `secondPtr` points to the `'w'` in `"world!"`, then it looks something like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| H | e | l | l | o |   | w | o | r | l | d | ! | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
^           ^           ^
|           |           |
str         firstPtr    secondPtr
```

So to print the "rest" of the string from e.g. `firstPtr` the figure above should make it obvious that you print it just like any other string.

The image should also make it very clear on how to get the number of characters between `firstPtr` and `secondPtr`, just subtract them: `secondPtr - firstPtr`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what is the sense to declare the first parameter when in fact it is not used in the function. Nevertheless the function can look like

```
void stringPointerOperation( const char *str, 
                             const char *firstPtr, 
                             const char *secondPtr )
{
    std::cout << firstPtr << std::endl;

    if ( secondPtr < firstPtr )
    {
        const char *p = firstPtr;
        firstPtr = secondPtr;
        secondPtr = p;
    }

    std::ptrdiff_t n = secondPtr - firstPtr;

    std::cout << "There are " << n 
              << " characters between pointers " 
              << ( const void * )firstPtr 
              << " and "
              << ( const void * )secondPtr
              << std::endl;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

void stringPointerOperation( const char *str, 
                             const char *firstPtr, 
                             const char *secondPtr )
{
    std::cout << firstPtr << std::endl;

    if ( secondPtr < firstPtr )
    {
        const char *p = firstPtr;
        firstPtr = secondPtr;
        secondPtr = p;
    }

    std::ptrdiff_t n = secondPtr - firstPtr;

    std::cout << "There are " << n 
              << " characters between pointers " 
              << ( const void * )firstPtr 
              << " and "
              << ( const void * )secondPtr
              << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    const char *s = "My name is Lewis Russell";

    stringPointerOperation( s, s + 11, s + 16 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Lewis Russell
There are 5 characters between pointers 0x8048b7a and 0x8048b7f
```

Type std::ptrdiff_t is simply a typedef for some signed int type. Usually it is `int`. So if you want you may replace `std::ptrdiff_t` with `int`.

If these statements

```
std::cout << str << std::endl;
std::cout << "First character=" << *firstPtr << std::endl;
std::cout << "Second character =" << *secondPtr << std::endl;
```

also have to be present in the function then you can include them in the code I showed.

```
void stringPointerOperation( const char *str, 
                             const char *firstPtr, 
                             const char *secondPtr )
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First character=" << *firstPtr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Second character =" << *secondPtr << std::endl;

    std::cout << firstPtr << std::endl;

    if ( secondPtr < firstPtr )
    {
        const char *p = firstPtr;
        firstPtr = secondPtr;
        secondPtr = p;
    }

    std::ptrdiff_t n = secondPtr - firstPtr;

    std::cout << "There are " << n 
              << " characters between pointers " 
              << ( const void * )firstPtr 
              << " and "
              << ( const void * )secondPtr
              << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "I do not understand what is the sense to declare the first parameter when in fact it is not used in the function." -- Look again.

Comment: @Jim Balter I have not understood what you wanted to say.

Comment: The problem statement, as quoted by the OP, includes `cout << str << endl;` ... that uses the first parameter. It is also a strong hint to the students as to how to solve item A.

Comment: @Jim Balter I answered his questions A and B. In the assignment there is not written that the string iteslf has to be outputed. But in any case he can insert his statements in the function I showed. There is no any problem.

Comment: I just explained to you why the first parameter is included ... the instructor's example code would not be valid without it. And nowhere does it say that the existing code should be removed; it's reasonable to assume that the code to output the values for A and B should be appended to the existing output.